# Javascript passing variable from on change to outside function using setAttribute and dropdown Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm converting a field in one of my tables from Free text to a dropdown with a set list of options. I then assign the selected value inside an onchange function, which is working correctly, however when I then try to assign this variable to the value element, using setAttribute, it isn't able to find it. I tried researching how to access variables outside of the scope of a function, but I wasn't able to link this to the set attribute method I'm using. If there is a better way to do this I will try this also.

The code below is called when the edit button is clicked on a form, if I remove all of the dropdown stuff and just use the free hand text of x.setAttribute("value",role) then it will pass the value through to the AJAX call no problem. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

```
  function editProcess(row,id,name,username,email,role){
      //WORKING
      $( "#name"+id+"" ).empty();
      var x = document.createElement("input");
      x.setAttribute("type", "text");
      x.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
      x.setAttribute("value", name);
      x.setAttribute("required", "true");
      x.setAttribute("style", "padding:0");
      x.setAttribute("name","name");
      x.setAttribute("onInput","clearPopUps()");
      $( "#name"+id+"" ).append(x);


      //NOT WORKING
      myParent = document.body;
      //Create array of options to be added
      var roleArray = ["Admin","Officer","Manager"];
      $( "#role"+id+"" ).empty();
      //Create and append select list
      var x = document.createElement("select");
      myParent.appendChild(x);

      //Create and append the options
      for (var i = 0; i < roleArray.length; i++) {
          var option = document.createElement("option");
          option.value = roleArray[i];
          option.text = roleArray[i];
          x.appendChild(option);       
      }
      $('#role').on('change', function() {
          role = $('#role option:checked').val();
          this.selectedOptions[0].setAttribute('value', role);
          x.setAttribute("value", role);
          console.log(x);
      });
      x.setAttribute("type", "text");
      x.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
      //x.setAttribute("value", selectedRole);
      x.setAttribute("required", "true");
      x.setAttribute("style", "padding:0");
      x.setAttribute("name","role");
      x.setAttribute("onInput","clearPopUps()");
      $( "#role"+id+"" ).append(x);
}
```

Comment: *the code below is called when the edit button is clicked on a form* - then can we assume that it's called multiple times?  Because you add `x.id="role"` to all of them and IDs must be unique for `$("#role")` to work.   Note that none of your code as provided requires the `"role"` select to have an id at all.  eg `$("#role").on` -> `$(x).on` and `role = $("#role option:checked").val()` -> `role = $(this).val()`.   Please also see [mcve] and provide a complete (minimal) sample that demonstrates the issue (edit and click `[<>]`)

Comment: *then it will pass the value through to the AJAX call* - which isn't included.  Are you making this ajax call before you've made a change on your "#role"?   What *exactly* is the value of `role` when you debug it?

Comment: yes, you're right assigning the role.id was incorrect, I've removed that. I've updated the function to show a column that is working in the edit, and then this <select> which isn't. I've narrowed it down so the issue specifically happens when I try to convert the normal input to a select.  Sorry I didn't include the rest because it is quite a lengthy piece of code which I've inherited.

Comment: And the value of role when I console log it inside the function is the selected dropdown value, eg "Admin".

Comment: 2 things jump out at me here, 1) Why use a combination of vanilla javascript and jQuery. Pick one, stick with it. 2) Re-using the variable `x` I think  is confusing you. Give these variables meaningful names and your problem would probably become much clearer (if not go away entirely) - also you no longer have an element with id `role` so `$("#role").on("change"....)` no longer makes any sense

Comment: Yeah I take your point with the mixing jquery and javascript. My original query was how to add a Select dropdown using set Attribute which I researched and then worked it into my solution above, would there be a better way to assign a dropdown then a value using setAttribute?

Comment: We need to see how you read the values when you call the AJAX. But I think you're misunderstanding what `setAttribute` does.

Comment: @Jamiec - The element id is still role, it would probably make more sense if I used `$('"#role"+id').on('change', function()` which takes the row id of the record

Comment: How can it be? The element id looks like it _starts with `role`_  (eg `role123`) but thats not the same thing

Comment: @Jamiec - yes actually you are completely right. I forgot I then had to assign a variable newRole and assign it to the selected option. The code I had there was actually working ok. I just had to add `var newRole = $('select[name=role] option:selected').val();` which then passed it through to my AJAX call. Thanks for the help and sorry for wasting your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the value of a dropdown using the `val()` method in jQuery or the `value` property in vanilla javascript.

```js
$("#using-jQuery").on("click", () => $("#test").val("2") )


document.getElementById("using-vanilla").addEventListener("click", 
     () => document.getElementById("test").value = "3" )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>


<button id="using-jQuery">Set to 2 using jQuery</button>
<button id="using-vanilla">Set to 3 using Vanilla JS</button>
```

Using `setAttribute` will not have the same effect!

```js
document.getElementById("using-vanilla").addEventListener("click", 
    () => document.getElementById("test").setAttribute("value","3") )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>


<button id="using-vanilla">Set to 3 using Vanilla JS + setAttribute</button>
```